# height: '100%' on a div not working, instead height = 0 in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a `div`, its style is `style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', overflow: "hidden" }}`, but in f12 the div is `100% by 0`

the div jsx component:

```
return (
    <div style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', overflow: "hidden" }}>
        {/* some code */}
    </div>
)
```

`App.css` style:

```
body, html {
    text-align: center;
}
```

The elements that wrap this div don't have any styles.

Comment: This is not a React issue but purely a CSS one. It is 100% relative to the parent. What is the parent?

Comment: if the parent has no height, the child has 100% of nothing if the child has no content

Answer (score 0):

If you need a particular div height, you can use px rather than a percentage. And if you need the **full height of the screen**, you can use viewport height.

Example:

`style={{ width: '100%', height: '100vh'}}`